# Netbeans stopped handling my makefile

Tags: c++, netbeans

I have all the sudden gotten a pretty annoying problem. Netbeans seems to have stopped handling the updates to my makefile.

This is the scenario:

1. I created a new c++ class, nothing fancy. Tested it in a separate main file. Compiled, no problem.
2. I created a second c++ class, went through the same process as the first one.

I get the error:

> ld: symbol(s) not defined for architecture x86_64

After some research, I see that my new c++ class is not being handled in the Makefile generated by Netbeans.

I have tried deleting the class and re-creating multiple times. But to no avail.